# mapview annotation not working in iphone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I don't know what's wrong with my code. This code work fine in iphone5 to higher version. In the first load of controller the map will show the country first then zoom in where the user point and the annotation show. Unfortunately, the iphone4s work different. It shows only the country then no more point or annotation show.

here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager * locationManager;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }
}


#pragma mark Map View
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *identifier = @"getLocation";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    CLGeocoder * geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error) {

        NSString *annTitle = @"Address unknown";

        if (placemark.count > 0)
        {
            CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemark objectAtIndex:0];
            annTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", topResult.locality];
        }

        MKPointAnnotation *toAdd = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        toAdd.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
        toAdd.title =annTitle;


        [self.mapView addAnnotation:toAdd];
    }];
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate] ,500,500);

        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];

    }];
}
```

and my viewcontroller.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@end
```

but I get this error

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

The errors shows only for iphone4s. The version of my iphone4s is ios8.

Comment: for permission you should use only one... not both...

Comment: Even I choose one permission. still nothing work. Does iphone4s recognize didUpdateUserLocation:?

Comment: Did you make entry in info.plist? NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription >> My App would like to use your location.

Comment: sorry late reply, I don't have plist. Honestly, I'm new for this. I will search your advice

Comment: info.plist always exist for each app.. it will be YourAppName-Info.plist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have not made entry in plist as shown below.

[image]

If still not working, update code to below.

```
myMapView.delegate = self;
locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    //        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
#endif
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[myMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[myMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[myMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

---

### Edit 1

As per your comment, you don't find info.plist.

You can find that in Supporting files.

[image]